# Identify row with number that is not in sequence

Tags: php, sql

I have a set of data that is not in sequential order.

```
No. Word
5   Hi
1   Hiii
2   Hiiiii
3   Hiiiiii
4   Hiiiiiii
```

How do I print out the first row using sql statement that indicates that this data is not in sequential order when it should be.

The output I want is:

```
No.5 is not in sequential order.
```

Comment: data set is not ordered unless you explicitly ordered it. In your example there is no column/expression that define the order of the rows (something that indicated that No.=5 is the first row etc.)

Comment: Please don't use images for data samples

Comment: Please confirm the database you are using

Comment: Assuming that performance doesn't matter, you could execute two queries - one is unordered, the other is ordered - and then compare the two results. As soon as an element differs the data isn't in sequential order.

Comment: I would like to insert those data into the database and just review them to check if they are in sequential order, if no i'll want to print out the row and then delete the data in the table. Hence, the database serves as a temporary storage.

Comment: id `No 5` a field on your db or calculated?

Comment: it is just a field!

Comment: and what is your rdbms? oracle, sql server, mysql ?

Comment: my database is mysql

Answer (score 0):

Hoping i understood your problem correctly.

Tried to create same problem in PostgreSql.

Please use below sql.

Sqlfiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63802/14/0

```
select col1 , col2
from
(
select col1, case when col1 = m  then 'Y'
else
case when 
col1-l=1 then 'Y' else 'N' end
end st, col2
from
(
select col1 , lag(col1)  over (order by  ctid)  l,
min(col1) over(order by col1) m  , col2
from so_test 
order by ctid
) a
) a
where st = 'N';
```

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `lead()` and `lag()` functions.  You can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(word) over (order by no) as prev_word,
             lead(word) over (order by no) as next_word
      from t
     ) t
where prev_word > word or next_word < word
order by word
fetch first 1 word only;
```

This outputs the first row that is "out of order".  You can us your application to format this as a particular message.

Comment: may i ask what's t.*? i assume it's the table name but what is the . and *?

Comment: @LimYunHui . . . That is a short-hand to select all the columns referred to by the table reference.